# Find specific Tag Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey I'm trying to extract URLs between 2 tags

This is what i got so far:

```
html_doc = '<div class="b_attribution" u="1|5075|4778623818559697|b0YAhIRjW_h9ERBLSt80gnn9pWk7S76H"><cite>https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...</cite><span class="c_tlbxTrg">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
links = []
for links in soup.findAll('cite'):
print(links.get('cite'))
```

I have tried different things but I couldn't extract the URL between
 `<cite>.....</cite>`

My code Updated

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

dorks = input("Keyword : ")

binglist = "http://www.bing.com/search?q="
    
with open(dorks , mode="r",encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        clean = binglist + line
        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(clean, headers=headers)
        soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
        links =  soup.find('cite')
        print(links)
```

In keyword file you just need to put any keyword like :
test
games

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try calling the `.text` method. `print(soup.find('cite').text)`

Comment: Probably you know, but you used the wrong type of quotation marks

Comment: I'll try you're fixe but i got an error : 
  `  links =  print(soup.find_all('cite').text)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
html_doc = '<div class="b_attribution" u="1|5075|4778623818559697|b0YAhIRjW_h9ERBLSt80gnn9pWk7S76H"><cite>https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...</cite><span class="c_tlbxTrg">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
links =  soup.find('cite')
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

You can webscrape Bing as follows:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cafari/537.36'}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search?q=test", headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
links =  soup.find('cite')


for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

This code does the following:

- With request we get the Web Page we're looking for. We set headers to avoid being blocked by Bing (more information, see: https://oxylabs.io/blog/5-key-http-headers-for-web-scraping)
- Then we *HTML'ify* the code, and extract **all** `code`tags (this returns a list)
- For each element in the list, we only want what's inside the `code`tag, using `.text` we print the inside of this tag.

Please pay attention to the headers!

Comment: Okay i'll try you're fix but i got : 
```  for link in links:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable```

Comment: That's means that links is `none`, so BeautifullSoup can't find any `cite`elements. Are you sure html_doc is retrieved right and *does* contain `cite` elements?

Comment: Yes I'm sure look here : [link](view-source:https://www.bing.com/search?q=test)

Sorry for the comment i can't edit like i want x)

Comment: Try printing `soup` and check wether that string containts `cite`elements. Some sites block webscrapers

Comment: I have trying in console and i successfull print : <cite>https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...</cite>
I don't no why i can't do it trough my program ..

Comment: Probably you're headers are wrong. Try the edited code

Comment: I've see you edited you're post with a Bing Web Scraping i've trying and that's work properly, but could you explain me how exatly you're new code work ?

Comment: You're amazing ! thanks a lots of, so now i can edit the code for doing this with a texte file with some keyword for get many website right ?

Comment: You sure can! Just replace the url and you are ready to go!

Comment: And the module for this line : links =  soup.find('cite') // It will find all the tag contains <cite> Right ? Sry for all question but i'm trying to understand for retry with an another search engine like yahoo for see if i have really understand

Comment: I have edited my original topic, if you can check if i have do it as well or not, really thanks for you're patience

Comment: Yeah that's right!  `links = soup.find('cite')` creates a list for a the `<cite>` tags!

Comment: So if i change tagg in like `links = soup.find_all('cite')` it should be give me all web site for the current word ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html_doc = '<div class="b_attribution" u="1|5075|4778623818559697|b0YAhIRjW_h9ERBLSt80gnn9pWk7S76H"><cite>https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...</cite><span class="c_tlbxTrg">'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
links =  soup.find_all('cite')
for link in links:
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Okay i'll try you're fix, i didn't get any error, but it didn't find text i want :/

Comment: Edited a minor mistake. Please try this now.

Comment: I got the same error, when i try to print i got no result the exact source i wan't to take is with bing search like in this source : view-source:https://www.bing.com/search?q=test

Comment: @Shereys Please don't just write the same as others

Comment: I've also tried in console python and i got same problem

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for this to get links from Bing organic results:

```py
# container with needed data: title, link, snippet, etc.
for result in soup.select(".b_algo"):
    link = result.select_one("h2 a")["href"]
```

Specifically for example provided by you:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '<div class="b_attribution" u="1|5075|4778623818559697|b0YAhIRjW_h9ERBLSt80gnn9pWk7S76H"><cite>https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...</cite><span class="c_tlbxTrg">'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
link = soup.select_one('.b_attribution cite').text
print(link)

# https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1497343/environnements-developpem...
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Bing-Scrape-Organic-Search-Results-Python-SerpApi#bs4_results/get_organic.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
  "q": "lasagna",
  "hl": "en",
}

html = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

for links in soup.select(".b_algo"):
    link = links.select_one("h2 a")["href"]
    print(link)

------------
'''
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/
https://www.foodnetwork.com/topics/lasagna
https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/
https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Bing Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/bing-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to deal with extraction, maintain, bypass from the blocks part, instead, you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get what you want.

Code to integrate to achieve your goal:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "bing",
  "q": "lion king"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    link = result['link']
    print(link)

------------
'''
https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/23600/worlds-best-lasagna/
https://www.foodnetwork.com/topics/lasagna
https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/best-lasagna/
https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/lasagna/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.